# passing structs to file functions

Tags: c, struct

hi guys im currently learning c and i have to pass a struct between multiple files for my project in uni . no matter what i do i keep getting errors when i try to pass a struct to a function. i have tired moving the function between being a global variable in main.c and i have tried putting it in a .h file, but i cannot figure it out, i keep hitting the same error messages when i try to gcc it . im having no problems using it in my main file but passing my variable to my functions in external files is where its getting errors i i will include my files that are relevant and my error messages when i gcc it. any help will be much appreciated cheers .

main.c

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    const int bufferSize=10;
    int const nBuffer = 50;
    char iptName [nBuffer];

    empInfo* info;
    info = (empInfo*)malloc(bufferSize * sizeof (empInfo));
    if (info == NULL){
        printf("*malloc* array not allocated\n");
    }
    printf("malloc worked");
    nameFinderPrinter(iptName,info,bufferSize);
    return;
}
```

fileFunctions.c

```
void nameFinderPrinter(char name[],empInfo* info, int size) {
   bool nameTF;

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
       if (strcmp(name, info[i].names )== 0);

       printf("%s age is %d wage is %f\n", info[i].names, info[i].ages, info[i].wages);
       nameTF=true;
   }
   if(nameTF ==false){
   printf("%s could not be found\n",name);}
   return;
}
```

struct.h

```
typedef  struct employeeInfo   
{
    char names[50]; 
    int ages;
    float wages; 
} empInfo;
```

error message on gcc

```
 In file included from main.c:7:
struct.h:1:17: error: redefinition of 'struct employeeInfo'
    1 | typedef  struct employeeInfo
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from fileFunctions.h:7,
                 from main.c:6:
struct.h:1:17: note: originally defined here
    1 | typedef  struct employeeInfo
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
struct.h:6:3: error: conflicting types for 'empInfo'; have 'struct employeeInfo'
    6 | } empInfo;
      |   ^~~~~~~
struct.h:6:3: note: previous declaration of 'empInfo' with type 'empInfo' {aka 'struct employeeInfo'}
    6 | } empInfo;
      |   ^~~~~~~
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:86:29: warning: passing argument 2 of 'nameFinderPrinter' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   86 |   nameFinderPrinter(iptName,info,bufferSize);
      |                             ^~~~
      |                             |
      |                             empInfo * {aka struct employeeInfo *}
fileFunctions.h:11:45: note: expected 'empInfo *' {aka 'struct employeeInfo *'} but argument is of type 'empInfo *' {aka 'struct employeeInfo *'}
   11 | void nameFinderPrinter(char name[],empInfo* info, int size);
```

i have tried using pointers to 'info[10]' and rewriting how i pass it to the function in every way i can think of only way that works is to send the internal information of the struct bit by bit like 'info[i].name' i have attempted to make info a global variable and accessing it in the function globally.  i am sorry if its messy i am still getting used to how to properly present my code on here and in general

Comment: Files should not make a difference. So please provide a single-file [mre] (MRE). If however that does make a difference please provide additionally a MRE with more than one file. Making that will probably provide an insight to you. Or make helping you easier. Also, please be sure to quote the error you get. At first do the most minimal MRE (i.e. of that of your attempts which can be shrunk the most), you might be asked then to provide a MRE for the second smallest, but functionally different attempt.

Comment: Mostly for prettiness, but often also for making analysis easier, please apply consistent indentation to your code.

Comment: Not really a problem, but the way you use `buffer` I would call it `bufferSize` or `sizeOfBuffer`.

Comment: Where are the error messages?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the source formatting. The code isn't readable.

Comment: i am sorry i am very new to this . is that a bit better? also sorry the error message is printed like code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "guards" around you header files:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_STRUCT_H
#define INCLUDE_STRUCT_H
typedef struct employeeInfo   
{
    char names[50]; 
    int ages;
    float wages; 
} empInfo; 
#endif
```

This prevents the content from being inserted twice. You included the header in main twice, once directly and once indirecty by including "fileFunctions.h", which itself includes it directly. This leads to the struct being defined twice in the same file. To prevent this these "guards" are used so it can only be included once.

Comment: thank you i will be mindful of that in the future , i added them to my file . i am still getting the error for the passing to the function

Comment: Only the last warning? Is there any other output, because that seems odd.

Comment: soo i recompile it today changed nothing and it works idk why but i'm guessing this done it thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers support `#pragma once`:

```c
#pragma once

typedef struct employeeInfo   
{
    char names[50]; 
    int ages;
    float wages; 
} empInfo;
```

This is simpler than defining header guards as suggested by Tenobaal.